# with animated images, replace the code from OnCreat function to setOnClickListener function

Tags: android

I am attempting to animate images, and this my code in xml file

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/father11" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/father22" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/father33" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/father44" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/father55" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

but in my application i have to run the animated images when the button clicked but i got sentax error

```
btn_father.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             SignImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Sign);
             SignImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.fatherr);
             lightsAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) SignImage.getDrawable();

            }
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
              super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
              lightsAnimation.start();

            }


    });
```

I read this sentece in the link but did not understand it "(if could easily have been started with a Button or other type of input). Replace the main class in the main.java file in the src tree with this class"

Comment: yes, it could easily have been started with a button or other type of imput, please paste your logcat to get actual problem

Comment: what do you mean by "your logcat"?

Comment: You are getting exception, so paste locat here

Comment: The method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) is undefined for the type Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, View.OnClickListener has only one method onClick, so if you want to start animation on click then do the following:

```
btn_father.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             SignImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Sign);
             SignImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.fatherr);
             lightsAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) SignImage.getDrawable();
             lightsAnimation.start();

            }


    });
```

If you want the animation to be applied on focus change too, then apply onFocusChanged listener on View.

Comment: thnxxxxxx, im just screaming right now, i did what you post, put stat function inside OnClick and then put onWindowFocusChanged in the class speratly, the wrong i did put function inside another lol